# I can't figure out how to remove a form field in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to achieve the following:

If user is admin, allow them to choose the blog author from a dropdown of users.  If not admin, remove the author field from admin completely.  The code I have works in that it removes the field from admin, but it doesn't allow a non admin user to save the form because presumably the author field exists and needs to be set to some value ie they get an error for the author field which isn't actually on the page.

I've tried multiple variations on this, including having 2 forms, one without the author field and one with it (this seems to break the published date for some reason) and I'm running out of ideas as to how to do this.  There's plenty of examples on SO and elsewhere but for either they don't fit my use case or don't appear to work (using django 1.6).

Any ideas?

```
#forms.py

class BlogForm(forms.ModelForm):

    author = forms.ModelChoiceField( queryset=User.objects.filter( Q(is_staff=True) ))

    class Meta:
        model = Blog

#admin.py
class BlogAdmin(AdminPlus):

    form = BlogForm

    default_fieldset = [( 'Publishing', {'fields': ['pub_date','is_published']} )]
    admin_fieldset = [( 'Publishing', {'fields': ['pub_date', 'author','is_published']} )]

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        current_user = request.user
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            self.exclude = ('author',)
        form = super(BlogAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.current_user = current_user
        return form    

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            return self.default_fieldset
        return self.admin_fieldset

admin.site.register(Blog, BlogAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `class BlogForm(forms.ModelForm)` , add following which does nothing :

```
def clean_author(self):
    author = self.cleaned_data['author']
    ## remove below 'if else' if u don't want to perform any validation.
    if self.current_user.is_superuser:
        ## perform superuser validation if you want otherwise simply pass
        pass
    else:
        ## perform non-superuser validation  if you want otherwise simply pass
        pass
    return author
```

**Not Tested** . but I hope its helpful for you . :)